# SoftKeyboard is not showing any keys and it's blank in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard

When I click on the edittext the keyboard is poping up. But the keyboard is blank. We can't see any keys on it, only grey color. It's happening in the BottomSheetDialogueFragment. Working normal in other pages. I'm attaching the screenshots.

[image: This is where the keyboard shows blank in BottomSheetDialogueFragment]

[image: This is where the keyboard working as normal everywhere else]

I tried different codes. But nothing worked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give  the XML and bottom sheet fragment code.